# Автоматический запуск brcmsmac

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Поставил на свой древний ноут 2 ОС: сперва стояла 7-я винда, потом на тот же диск, рядом, установил Ubuntu. Работаю с Линуксом впервые. Чтобы подключиться к Wi-fi приходится при каждом запуске запускать драйвер:

```
~$ sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Но каждый раз запускать как-то не удобно. Есть ли вариант чтобы он автоматически это делал? В и-нете не могу найти ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создайте файл **/etc/modules-load.d/brcmsmac.conf**
куда добавьте строку

```
brcmsmac
```

подробнее [описано в арчвики](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_module#Automatic_module_loading)